# Error al integrar SDK Paypal en Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, paypal, sdk, next.js

estoy intentando integrar el SDK de Paypal a mi página y aparentemente funciona, sin embargo, cuando alguien quiere realizar una compra, no se le debita el pago y a mí no me llega nada (problema raro).

Está claro que no soy profesional en Nextjs y lo más probable es que esté haciendo mal la integración.

Esta es la página, pueden chequear en la consola que está lleno de errores de paypal: https://minehosting.fun/
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá está el desarrollo: https://github.com/gabenitez0/minehosting

1. En "pages/_app.js" está la integración del SDK de paypal.
2. En "components/Tienda/mediosPago/paypal.js" está el botón.
3. En "components/Tienda/Producto.js" se imprime el botón.

¿Qué estoy haciendo mal o cómo lo puedo solucionar? Desde ya muchas gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué errores te salen? ¿Los puedes compartir?

Comment: @FranAcuna ahi lo agregue a la publicación